# How to keep seperate VisualStudio window on same/next z-level as main window?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I use VisualStudioCommunity 2017 15.4.1 and opened an extra editor window. I click on the VisualStudio main window to bring it to the front.

I would expect the extra window to also come to front. However, the extra VisualStudio window still hides behind another application (e.g. my browser window). I have to manually bring it to the front.

=>How can I tell VisualStudio to keep the z-order of its windows next to each other to be able to bring all of its windows to the front with only one click?

Comment: It used to work this way in old VS versions.  Not exactly sure when this was changed, VS2013 or earlier.  The old behavior wasn't very desirable, all floating windows would move back into the foreground, not just the one you wanted.  Well, it is not like it is hard to get back to the window, there is an extra taskbar button for it and the Windows menu lists it.  Use Help > Send Feedback to tell them what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the **Floating tab wells always stay on top of the main window** option to make extra editors activate and hide as the main window:

[image]